# Generate PowerPoint-like presentation for electronic notice board on TV

Tags: presentation

In my office we changed the classical paper notice board to a 50" TV for the sake of modern look.

Is there some easy way to generate a PowerPoint-like presentation with a vertical menu in the left, and in the center-right the scan of the notices?

I created one manually but in the long run adding notices consumes a lot of time so I prefer to use a software, even paid, in order to automate that.

Please see the image for what my e-noticeboard looks like:

Edit: I'm using powerpoint indeed, but if you have, for example, 7 notices and you want to add 2 new notices you will need to 1) move all the 7 notices down , 2) add 2 new notices to the left, and multiply that by 9 pages. So I prefer to use some publishing software that would permit : 1) add new notice, 2) write notice title 3) upload page, and it automates the new form. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Why not use Powerpoint?

Comment: depaul: To re-obtain ownership of your question, you might wish to see [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: This question sounds as if you have an ordinary Windows PC with video output to the monitor. If this is the case, you only need additional software to create your powerpoints or other output format (HTML in a browser?). In that case, please edit everything about your monitor out of your question, it is irrelevant and confuses the readers. If my assumption is incorrect, tells us what hardware you actually use, full make/models with links, and what is *upload page* - i.e. what formats?

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using a Raspberry Pi connected to the HDMI port of the TV, possibly powered from the USB port, (most have one), or similar running a presentation with [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/) Present which is free, cross platform and will run very nicely on the Pi, etc.